# Being thrown an error that my angular js function isn't defined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=ProjectsController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

I mimicked a ng-repeat that I did earlier, the only difference being I didn't split up the directive, controller, and initializing the app into 3 different javascript files. Also, are you allowed to add multiple ng-apps to the `<body>` tag? If no, then that may be my problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="projects"> 
    <h2>Projects</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row" ng-controller="ProjectsController">
                <div class="project-boxes" ng-repeat="project in projects">
                    <project-info info="project"></project-info>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var projectApp = angular.module("projectApp", ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.projects = [
    {
        link: '#',
        img: 'img/box.jpeg',
        description: 'Project 1'
    }];
}])
.directive('projectsInfo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'components/projects/projects-template/projectsInfo.html'
  };
});
```

Comment: Use only one ng-app in your app.

Comment: Single ng-app, though you can use multiple controllers

Comment: You mean in the body? @VishalRajole

Comment: You can use ng-app anywhere. From that point, compiler will come to know that next code is angular code. Go through documentation first.

Comment: @Beartums Thank you. But when I tried the ng-repeat, it didn't work, but I was still able to output a basic $scope title = 'test' element

Comment: And, for controller undefined error, check you have included js file in source paths.

Comment: @VishalRajole Your insight about too many apps was the problem, however the ng-repeat doesnt work still even though the function works properly

Comment: Do you still get the controller undefined error?